# lock double click in form header

Tags: vb.net

I need to lock double click in form header. Is it possible?
I need this because I don´t that the user can maximize or minimize the form.
I change the MaximumSize and MinimumSize but when I do double click in form header, the form Minimize 1 px approximately. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You disable minimizing and maximizing by setting the form's MinimizeBox and MaximizeBox to False.  That also stops double-clicking the window's title bar from having any effect.  And the commands are disabled in the system menu as well.

You disable resizing by setting the FormBorderStyle to one of the Fixed values.

Comment: Hi, I did that but not works, I don´t mentioned that the forms are in a tabcontrol

Comment: Hmm, yes, you certainly didn't.  That's quite inappropriate, you *must* set the FormBorderStyle to None.  Nevertheless, my solution still works.

Comment: mm, what is the correct way? Using user control ? I don´t found any example and I don´t do :(. If i set the FormBorderStyle to none, how I close the tab? sorry

Comment: @WFgo: How can a form be in a tab control? And how can it have a title bar then?

Comment: This is rapidly derailing.  I have to recommend you add a plain  button to the upper right corner of the tab page.

Comment: I didn't know about the `TopLevel` property. However if you set `MaximizeBox` and `MinimizeBox` to false as suggested the form won't maximize/minimize (I just checked that). Maybe `WindowState` is set to `FormWindowState.Maximized`?

Comment: @pescolino yes the WindowsState is set to FormWindowsState.Maximized.

Comment: Then set it to `Normal` (or leave `WindowState` untouched since `Normal` is the default value)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, except I'm not using a TabControl, just a regular old Form.

I have a form whose *FormBorderStyle* property is set to **Fixed3D**, and its *MaximizeBox* property is set to **False** (the form initializes with *WindowState* **Maximized**). The MaximizeBox is always disabled at runtime, which is appropriate, but double-clicking the title bar "restores" the window from a Maximized state to a Normal state... *the first time*. It seems that it's only *after* you've double-clicked the title bar once that this ability becomes disabled, because double-clicking the title bar a second time doesn't maximize the window.

Is there a way around this ridiculous unexplained behaviour?
(Using VB 2005 w/ 2.0 SDK on Win7)